# Android O HIDL not available

Tags: android, android-source, android-hardware, hal, android-8.0-oreo

I have problem with Android O HIDL. The failure log shows it can't find out the service.

However I can see it by `adb shell ps -A | grep fingerprint`

```
system       18758     1   17408   3276 pipe_wait  7c79e93e08 R android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service`
```

Could anyone give me a hint how to solve the problem? I checked https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/ but could not get the solution.

Error log:

```
08-21 06:00:35.864  1890  2264 V FingerprintService: mDeamon was null, reconnect to fingerprint
08-21 06:00:35.864  1890  2264 I system_server: Looking for service android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint/default
08-21 06:00:35.864  2240  2240 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Set mode ifindex 24 iftype 2 (STATION)
08-21 06:00:35.866   566   566 W /system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransportFromManifest: Cannot find entry android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint in either framework or device manifest, using default transport.
08-21 06:00:35.866  1890  2264 E system_server: service android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1::IBiometricsFingerprint declares transport method EMPTY but framework expects hwbinder.
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService: Failed to get biometric interface
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService: android.os.RemoteException: HwBinder Error: (-2147483648)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService:    at android.os.HwBinder.getService(Native Method)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService:    at android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint.V2_1.IBiometricsFingerprint.getService(IBiometricsFingerprint.java:44)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService:    at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService.getFingerprintDaemon(FingerprintService.java:239)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService:    at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService$FingerprintServiceWrapper.isHardwareDetected(FingerprintService.java:1198)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService:    at android.hardware.fingerprint.IFingerprintService$Stub.onTransact(IFingerprintService.java:156)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 E FingerprintService:    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
08-21 06:00:35.867  1890  2264 W FingerprintService: fingerprint HIDL not available
```

Answer (score 5):

I've succeeded in running my fingerprint HAL on Android 8.1 executing on HiKey 
 96 board after modified files as below.

Firstly, it's necessary that adding HIDL configures to declare a device as a vendor or you would get VTS failed.

```
About HIDL configures
device/linaro/hikey/manifest.xml
+<hal format="hidl">
    <name>android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint</name>
    <transport>hwbinder</transport>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <interface>
        <name>IBiometricsFingerprint</name>
        <instance>default</instance>
    </interface>
</hal>
```

Secondly, finger service will be started after you define it in the file below.

```
device/linaro/hikey/device-common.mk
+#init finger service and copy
 android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service.rc to 
 system/vendor/etc/init
+PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    +android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service
    +# copy permission file of finger service
+PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    +frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.fingerprint.xml:system/etc
    /permissions/android.hardware.fingerprint.xml
```

Finally, check finger service has been started and running in Android system by using terminal commands such as "adb shell" and "ps | grep finger".

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I  need to add the code to the manifest.xml
(Ref. https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vintf/objects )

```
    <hal format="hidl">
        <name>android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint</name>
        <transport>hwbinder</transport>
        <impl level="generic"></impl>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <interface>
            <name>IBiometricsFingerprint</name>
            <instance>default</instance>
        </interface>
    </hal>
```