# screenrecord not capturing frames in android oreo 8.1?

Tags: android, selinux

I am trying to capture screen behaviour. Used screenrecord application to capture screen for 3 minutes but not able to capture a single frame.

screencap works fine.

I have tried to use vysor/scrcpy - input(mouse) events works but no frames/video on PC.

I have AOSP code, i would like to explore the code. i'm looking for pointers to which android framework files i should look.

**Oreo 8.0 screenrecord/vysor works.**

**Oreo 8.1 screenrecord/vysor fails.**

logcat:

> 01-01 04:48:56.479   631   631 W Binder:631_3: type=1400
> audit(0.0:176): avc: denied { call } for
> scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:mediacodec:s0
> tclass=binder permissive=0
>
> 01-01 04:48:56.535   416   416 W
> /system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransport: getTimeAtTime:
> vendor.display.config@1.1::IDisplayConfig/default in either framework
> or device manifest.
>
> 01-01 04:48:56.537   416   416 W
> /system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry
> vendor.display.config@1.1::IDisplayConfig/default in either framework
> or device manifest.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is tied to your particular hardware.

Comment: can confirm no issue with hardware. works fine with oreo 8.0.

Comment: `adb logcat` might show relevant logs to find the actual error

Comment: Sorry, by "your particular hardware", I was referring more to the firmware, not the actual chips and stuff. The Android build for that hardware would appear to have some sort of bug or limitation that is causing your difficulty. These tools work for Android 8.1 in general.

Comment: @rom1v, i have added logcat snip. my doubt is on avc denial.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/configstore ... it is unlikely to be SElinux related, when other values can be read. `build flags defined in the same interface are affected by same SELinux policy.` can you reproduce the issue on an emulator??

Comment: @MartinZeitler, i have used android studio for screenrecord same result. zero frame captured.

Comment: @GBiradar you'd probably need a rooted device to see the SE Linux audit log - else it's guessing.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, i am using rooted device. I have cross check selinux permission. Allowed permission for surfaceflinger (adb logcat -b all -d | audit2allow -p policy) still issue persist.

Comment: @GBiradar would compare permissions and SE labels on Android 8.0 vs. 8.1 ...just found this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45851810/549372

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I have updated permissions & labels. I am not getting any avc denial or label issue but still issue persist.